# Changing the type of attribute in Hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I had an attribute in an itemtype defined to be String. I changed the type of the attribute to Enumeration. However I am trying to update the existing values with an `INSERT_UPDATE` to one of the existing enum values and getting the following exception:

> java.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal representation

How to go about in this case?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the same as your previous question. ([Redefining data type in items.xml in Hybris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45849416/redefining-data-type-in-items-xml-in-hybris)It) is not wise to change the type of an attribute. I would recommend to create a new field (with different name and use it for future) or just restore a previous copy of your DB.

Answer (score 0):

I had this kind of error only when I don't update the system via HAC.

Answer (score 0):

System update won't change the dataType. 
For Local: you can do an initialize with the new sample data.(for that particular Enum change).

For higher environments: You have to directly operate on the database. Alter the database column data first with the corresponding ENUM's PK value and then change the type of the database column to LONG

Answer (score 0):

Update the running system!
hac > Platform > Update

[image]